# Organize .txt file into data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a .txt file that looks exactly like this:

```
ENVI ASCII Plot File [Sun Mar  5 00:06:04 2017]
Column 1: Band Number
Column 2: Mean: red_1 [Magenta] 20 points~~7
Column 3: Mean: red_2 [Red] 12 points~~2 
Column 4: Mean: red_3 [Green] 12 points~~3
Column 5: Mean: red_4 [Blue] 15 points~~4
Column 6: Mean: red_5 [Yellow] 20 points~~5
Column 7: Mean: red_6 [Cyan] 25 points~~6
Column 8: Mean: red_7 [Maroon] 16 points~~8
Column 9: Mean: red_8 [Sea Green] 6 points~~9
Column 10: Mean: red_9 [Purple] 12 points~~10
Column 11: Mean: red_10 [Coral] 6 points~~11
Column 12: Mean: bcs_1 [Aquamarine] 16 points~~12
Column 13: Mean: bcs_2 [Orchid] 16 points~~13
Column 14: Mean: bcs_3 [Sienna] 30 points~~14
Column 15: Mean: bcs_4 [Chartreuse] 16 points~~15
Column 16: Mean: bcs_5 [Thistle] 25 points~~16
Column 17: Mean: bcs_6 [Red1] 16 points~~17
Column 18: Mean: bcs_7 [Red2] 15 points~~18
Column 19: Mean: bcs_8 [Red3] 12 points~~19
Column 20: Mean: bcs_9 [Green1] 20 points~~20
Column 21: Mean: bcs_10 [Green2] 20 points~~21
1.000000  0.061581  0.078073  0.057892  0.065844  0.090056  0.088098     0.089036  0.077258  0.055721  0.124091  0.037674  0.040654  0.037246  0.049291  0.041737  0.052611  0.059882  0.057625  0.054079  0.053647
2.000000  0.042688  0.037923  0.045340  0.046383  0.046419  0.047063  0.053226  0.049161  0.028502  0.026902  0.057672  0.045742  0.028775  0.041979  0.038616  0.046102  0.053043  0.029172  0.045776  0.040539
3.000000  0.018434  0.036316  0.032751  0.024035  0.027343  0.027738  0.036514  0.014953  0.022183  0.034359  0.010836  0.014596  0.011336  0.014386  0.011091  0.016790  0.014971  0.016921  0.016966  0.019890
4.000000  0.018490  0.015526  0.018201  0.014678  0.016888  0.013276  0.024992  0.019930  0.014847  0.007780  0.018094  0.009815  0.006283  0.014529  0.012734  0.009747  0.011569  0.007291  0.013920  0.008032
```

And I would like to make a data frame where each ROI (i.e. red_1, red_2, red_3, etc...) is a row and the Band Number values are columns. This will involve transposing the data, which I don't know how to do. The final data frame should look like this:

```
ROI    Band_1    Band_2   Band_3   Band_4
Red_1  0.061581  0.042688 0.018434 0.018490
Red_2  0.078073. 0.037923 0.036316 0.018489 
... and so forth
```

So far I have this:

```
# create an index for the lines that are needed
txt[-1:-22] # removes all rows except data

# find lines with names of ROIs
rep_date_entries = grep("Mean:", txt)
```

Any leads on how to transpose the values would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Oh shoot! I didn't realize that. I give an attempt and then edit the question.

Comment: The thing is... I don't even know where to start. Any recommendations @TigerHawkT3?

Comment: Yes: tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Any leads specifically? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
# reading the text file
txt <- readLines('name_of_file.txt')

# extract the columnnames from the text file
colnms <- sapply(strsplit(grep('^Column ', txt, value = TRUE),':'), function(i) trimws(tail(i,1)))
colnms <- sub('(\\w+).*', '\\1', colnms)

# reading the data lines into a dataframe with 'read.table'
# and use the 'col.names' parameter to assign the column names
dat <- read.table(text = txt, skip = 22, header = FALSE, col.names = colnms)

# reshape the data into the desired format
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- recast(dat, variable ~ paste0('Band_',Band), id.var = 'Band')
names(dat2)[1] <- 'ROI'
```

will give:

```
> dat2
      ROI   Band_1   Band_2   Band_3   Band_4
1   red_1 0.061581 0.042688 0.018434 0.018490
2   red_2 0.078073 0.037923 0.036316 0.015526
3   red_3 0.057892 0.045340 0.032751 0.018201
4   red_4 0.065844 0.046383 0.024035 0.014678
5   red_5 0.090056 0.046419 0.027343 0.016888
6   red_6 0.088098 0.047063 0.027738 0.013276
7   red_7 0.089036 0.053226 0.036514 0.024992
8   red_8 0.077258 0.049161 0.014953 0.019930
9   red_9 0.055721 0.028502 0.022183 0.014847
10 red_10 0.124091 0.026902 0.034359 0.007780
11  bcs_1 0.037674 0.057672 0.010836 0.018094
12  bcs_2 0.040654 0.045742 0.014596 0.009815
13  bcs_3 0.037246 0.028775 0.011336 0.006283
14  bcs_4 0.049291 0.041979 0.014386 0.014529
15  bcs_5 0.041737 0.038616 0.011091 0.012734
16  bcs_6 0.052611 0.046102 0.016790 0.009747
17  bcs_7 0.059882 0.053043 0.014971 0.011569
18  bcs_8 0.057625 0.029172 0.016921 0.007291
19  bcs_9 0.054079 0.045776 0.016966 0.013920
20 bcs_10 0.053647 0.040539 0.019890 0.008032
```

The last step of reshaping the data can also be done with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(dat), id = 1, variable.name = 'ROI'), ROI ~ paste0('Band_',Band))
```

Comment: Hi @Jaap. One more question.  My code is not outputting `Band_1` when I use a text file with more ROIs than the example I gave here. Can you indicate which line of code selects Band_1, Band_2, etc and puts them into columns?

Comment: @JAG2024 `max(grep('^Column ', txt))` will give you the value of the last line that starts with *"Column"*. That value should be used for the `skip` parameter in `read.table`.